# How can I separate multiple graphs in this code?

Tags: python, graph, subplot

I'm new learner of python. I am trying to split the graphs into 4 separated blocks. I know I need to use subplots but I dont know how to. Here is my code Im trying right now.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['lines.color'] = 'k'
mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = mpl.cycler('color', ['k'])
x = np.linspace(-9, 9, 400)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 400)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

def axes():
    plt.axhline(0, alpha=.1)
    plt.axvline(0, alpha=.1)

a = 0.3
axes()
plt.contour(x, y, (y**2 - 4*a*x), [2], colors='k')
plt.show()

a1 = 2
b1= 2
axes()
plt.contour(x, y,(x**2/a1**2 + y**2/b1**2), [1], colors='k')
plt.show()

a = 4.0
b = 2.0
axes()
plt.contour(x, y,(x**2/a**2 + y**2/b**2), [1], colors='k')
plt.show()

a = 2.0
b = 1.0
axes()
plt.contour(x, y,(x**2/a**2 - y**2/b**2), [1], colors='k')
plt.show()
```

I've tried

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 2)

a = 0.3
axes()
ax[0].plot(x, y, (y**2 - 4*a*x), [2], colors='k')
plt.show()
```

and

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 2)

def practice():
   a = 0.3
   axes()
   ax[0].plot(x, y, (y**2 - 4*a*x), [2], colors='k')
ax[0].plot(practice)
```

either way dosent work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.subplots` returns a 2D array of axes.
So, you must call `plot` or `contour` on `ax[i,j]` `i` and `j` being integers, not on `plt` or `ax[i]`.

Besides, that goes also for your `axhline` and `axvline`

Lastly, you must call `plt.show()` only once if you want one window to show up.

So

```py
# Untouched code before that
def axes(ax):
    ax.axhline(0, alpha=.1)
    ax.axvline(0, alpha=.1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 2)

a = 0.3
axes(ax[0,0])
ax[0,0].contour(x, y, (y**2 - 4*a*x), [2], colors='k')

a1 = 2
b1= 2
axes(ax[0,1])
ax[0,1].contour(x, y,(x**2/a1**2 + y**2/b1**2), [1], colors='k')

a = 4.0
b = 2.0
axes(ax[1,0])
ax[1,0].contour(x, y,(x**2/a**2 + y**2/b**2), [1], colors='k')

a = 2.0
b = 1.0
axes(ax[1,1])
ax[1,1].contour(x, y,(x**2/a**2 - y**2/b**2), [1], colors='k')

plt.show()
```

(Note that I kept your `subplots` parameters, and then your 4 plots. But, of course, `subplots(3,2)` creates 3x2=6 subgraphs, not 4. So 2 of them remain empty after this code.

[image: Result]